# Change function on javascript prototype

Tags: javascript, ajax, function, prototype, overriding

I want to change the XMLHttpRequest send function so that a function is called before the request is made and after the request is complete. Here is what I have so far:

```
var oldSend = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send;
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = function() {
    //this never gets called
    oldOnReady = this.onreadystatechange;
    this.onreadystatechange = function() {
        oldOnReady();
        ajaxStopped();
    }

    ajaxStarted();

    // according to http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/
    // there's only ever 0 or 1 parameters passed into this method
    if(arguments && arguments.length > 0) {
        oldSend(arguments[0]); //gets to here, calls this method, then nothing happens
    } else {
        oldSend();
    }
}

function ajaxStarted() {
    ajaxCount++;
    document.getElementById("buttonClicky").innerHTML = "Count: " + ajaxCount;
}

function ajaxStopped() {
    $("#isRunning")[0].innerHTML = "stopped";
    ajaxCount--;
    document.getElementById("buttonClicky").innerHTML = "Count: " + ajaxCount;
}
```

However, I'm doing something wrong here because once it hits the `oldSend()` call, it never returns or triggers the `onreadystatechange` event. So I must be doing somethingclickCount wrong here.  Any ideas? I set a breakpoint and it gets hit just fine when I call this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "file.txt",
    success: function(result) {
                    //this never gets called
        document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = result;
    }
});
```

So my new function is getting called. I guess just don't know how to call the old function. Any ideas on how to fix this code so that the Ajax Request is actually made and my new callback gets called?

Note: I'm aware of the JQuery events that essentially do this. But I'm doing this so I can get it to work with any Ajax call (Mootools, GWT, etc). I am just happening to test it with Jquery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call `old` functions in the context of `this`.

E.g.: oldSend.call(this)

Comment: so would I do this: `oldSend.call(this, arguments[0]);` or is there a better way where I can just pass in the arguments array? Thus eliminating the if statement.

Comment: You can use `.apply()` which takes an array as the second parameter.